# Three.js First Person Controls moves the camera all the time

Tags: user-controls, three.js

The game I'm designing currently requires a first person controller and luckily Three.js offers that class as well.

However I can't stop the camera from flying around. I know that the mouse movement causes the fly because it happens as soon as I move the mouse. But reading the js code,I cant find the attribue which causes this movement. Here is how I initiate the controls:

```
controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
controls.movementSpeed = 0.1;
controls.lookSpeed = 0.001;
controls.lookVertical = true;
```

I do not want the view direction to change when I am not moving the mouse.

any idea ?

Comment: Try alternative : https://maximumroulette.com/apps/matrix-engine/examples-build.html
Source: https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/matrix-engine Activation FP Camera in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that the FPS style mouse movement in webGL is usable rather only in a full screen mode. If an application runs in a standard windowed mode, the cursor is visible, and the application can not detect cursor movements that cross the edge of the window. This makes it impossible to look around in the FPS style (look movement stops when the cursors reaches the window edge).

This is probably the main reason why a `PointerLockControls` demo asks you to switch to the full screen mode.

With `FirstPersonControls` the look movement continues when the mouse reaches the edge. Such approach works well in the windowed mode.

Comment: Your answer was good enough to make me change the best answer to this one.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the PointerLockControls instead

See an example here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html

Comment: Having the cursor in the screen is a requirement for my game. I need to pick different objects with the pointer.

Comment: You could add an object in the middle of the screen, in front of the camera to act as an pointer

Comment: Thank you for the example, I had thought about it as a solution, but what I actually want is the ability to click and select objects. How can I tell which object was clicked without a cursor and with another object?

Comment: With the example you can add the cursor and with the THREE.raycaster you can 'cast a ray' from the camera (First Person) to where you clicked. Where the first intersect is the object you need. But I advise you to post another question about that